# rails ajax request to namespaced route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, summernote

I'm trying to send ajax POST request to /images.
In routes.rb I have this:

```
namespace :admin, path: '/' do
...
  resources :images, only: %w[create destroy]
...
end
```

that gives me these routes (rake routes output):

```
admin_images_path   POST    /images(.:format)   admin/images#create {:subdomain=>"admin"}
admin_image_path    DELETE  /images/:id(.:format)   admin/images#destroy {:subdomain=>"admin"}
```

And there is an Ajax request that looks like this:

```
$.ajax
      data: data
      type: 'POST'
      url: '/images'
      cache: false
      contentType: false
      processData: false
      success: (data) ->
        console.log("success")
```

For some reason, that request is resulting 404 error:

```
POST http://admin.example.com/images 404 (Not Found)
```

What could be reason for that behavior?
Thanks in advance!

UPD. For test purposes I tried to use this route without namespace. The error is gone. But I can't leave it like this.

Comment: are the routes you shown copied from the output of rake routes?

Comment: @rks thanks for the question. I've made corrections to that part in the post.

Comment: share code for your images controller as well, it should be namespaced into admin

Comment: can you paste it down the error log apart from 404.

Comment: @rks I was sure I generated it in admin namespace, but found out it's not. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @VishalTajPM thanks for the response! problem solved